# Updating and Deleting Comments for Posts in Django Project not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have added a Comment system to posts in a Blog Project and I am trying to add an option to update and delete the comments by the users who created the comment.

I am trying to use the same concept as creating a Post and building a CBV for these comments.

Creating a comment is working fine and it is appearing correctly, the only obstacle I am facing is the slug, when a user clicks on the update or delete button on update or delete it returns the following error:

`Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into the field. Choices are content, created, id, post, post_id, updated, user, user_id` which makes sense since there is no Slug in the comment Model.

My question is how to update or delete a comment and return back to the same page post.slug in the template without getting this error?

Here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=120)
    ------------------------------------------------------------

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300, validators=[validate_comment_text])
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is the views.py

```
class PostCommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = post
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs=dict(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))


class PostCommentUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content']  # What needs to appear in the page for update
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs=dict(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))

    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.user:
            return True
        return False


class PostCommentDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'blog/postcomment_confirm_delete.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.user:
            return True
        return False

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs=dict(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))
```

here is the urls.py

```
    path('blog/<slug:slug>/update_comment/',
         PostCommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-commentu'),
    path('blog/<slug:slug>/delete_comment/',
         PostCommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-commentd'),
```

here is the template:

```
{% if comment.user == user %}
<div>
<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'blog:post-commentu' post.slug %}">Update</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'blog:post-commentd' post.slug %}">Delete</a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: try `post__slug` here  `return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs=dict(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))` or where exactly does the error accure?

Comment: @hansTheFranz I added an `href="{% url 'blog:post-commentu' post.slug %}` to update the comment related to the user but when i click it it returns the error `Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: content, created, id, post, post_id, updated, user, user_id`